# Not able to log-in ubuntu using pkcs#11 module

Tags: 14.04

With the pkcs#11 module we are not able to log-in to ubuntu operating system. Here for this, we have taken reference from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557180 https://opensc.github.io/pam_pkcs11/doc/pam_pkcs11.html#idp2059072

When trying to log-in using pkcs#11 shared library, facing error like-

`ubuntu kernel: [13342.185619] lightdm[15882]: segfault at b662b48e ip b71ddd2f sp bfb35dec error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7163000+1a8000]`

Getting this error after exit from C_Finalize (Traced using syslog)..

At log-in Screen messages getting like- `Smartcard authentication starts, 
Smart card found, 
verifying certificate, 
Failed to authenticate`

when tried through terminal to log-in other user from default user- able to get `authentication succeeded` at the end(before Segmentation fault in terminal) and getting error(as per syslog) -

`ubuntu kernel: [11694.542754] su[13543]: segfault at b676048e ip b7586d2f sp bfd0f0bc error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b750c000+1a8000]`

Can any one help us by giving solution to debug this...

Note: In addition to our shared library, we are using smart card for log-in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in trace statements.. Internally we called syslog() in trace, here bug raised because of not closing the log (i.e: closelog() is missing). Now there is no problem with the module..